# Where to get PKI module for powershell

Tags: powershell, module, pki

I need to get pki.psm1 file for the PKI module. Not pspki, not pkiclient, not pkitools, just pki. I need cmdlet Import-Certificate, which isn't in any of the above-mentioned modules, only in PKI. When I tried to copy the module folder from a windows 10 computer with PS 5.1, the psm1 file is missing there and the module therefore doesn't work in lower versions of PS. I need to use it in PS 2.0 if possible, since we have lots of those in our environment. Does anyone know, where can I get complete PKI module?

Answer (score 1):

This Microsoft module was supplied with WMF 5.0 on Windows 10

If you look at the module details it is not compatible below Powershell 3.0:

```
@{
GUID="{cf094c6b-63d1-4dda-bf70-15a602c4eb2b}"
Author="Microsoft Corporation"
CompanyName="Microsoft Corporation"
Copyright="© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved."
ModuleVersion="1.0.0.0"
NestedModules="Microsoft.CertificateServices.PKIClient.Cmdlets"
TypesToProcess = 'pki.types.ps1xml'
HelpInfoUri="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=390811"
PowerShellVersion='3.0'
CLRVersion='4.0'
CmdletsToExport = @('Add-CertificateEnrollmentPolicyServer', 'Export-Certificate', 'Export-PfxCertificate', 'Get-CertificateAutoEnrollmentPolicy', 'Get-Certificate', 'Get-CertificateNotificationTask', 'Get-CertificateEnrollmentPolicyServer', 'Get-PfxData', 'Import-Certificate', 'Import-PfxCertificate', 'New-CertificateNotificationTask', 'New-SelfSignedCertificate', 'Remove-CertificateNotificationTask', 'Remove-CertificateEnrollmentPolicyServer', 'Set-CertificateAutoEnrollmentPolicy', 'Switch-Certificate', 'Test-Certificate')
}
```